# Interpolation_ the treatment of the first several rows with NaN

Tags: python, spyder

I was trying to convert all the 0s and NAs in a dataframe s.t. I could do further calculations. Here is an example.

### symbol|    tdate| tclose

```
 1| 20150105|   0
 1| 20150106|   15.78
 1| 20150107|   15.48
 1| 20150108|   14.96
 1| 20150109|   15.08
 2| 20150105|   14.91
 2| 20150106|   NA
 2| 20150107|   0
 2| 20150108|   0
 2| 20150109|   13.45
 3| 20150105|   15.69
 3| 20150106|   16.46
 3| 20150107|   16.41
 3| 20150108|   0
 3| 20150109|   0
```

E.g.for 0 in symbol 1, I wish the 0 to be the nearest value that is not 0 or NaN, i.e. 15.78.
For 0/Na in symbol 2, I wish the 0/NaN to the interpolation result using 14.91 and 13.45.
After converting, it should look like this.

### symbol|    tdate| tclose

```
 1| 20150105|   15.78
 1| 20150106|   15.78
 1| 20150107|   15.48
 1| 20150108|   14.96
 1| 20150109|   15.08
 2| 20150105|   14.91
 2| 20150106|   14.18
 2| 20150107|   14.18
 2| 20150108|   14.18
 2| 20150109|   13.45
 3| 20150105|   15.69
 3| 20150106|   16.46
 3| 20150107|   16.41
 3| 20150108|   16.41
 3| 20150109|   16.41
```

I have tried something like

```
df=pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/stackoverflow.csv')
df1=df.replace(0,np.nan)
for i in range(1,len(df1)):
    df2=df1[df1.symbol==i]
    df3=pd.DataFrame(df2.interpolate())
    print(df3)
```

which gives you

### symbol|    tdate| tclose

```
 1| 20150105|   NaN
 1| 20150106|   15.78
 1| 20150107|   15.48
 1| 20150108|   14.96
 1| 20150109|   15.08
 2| 20150105|   14.91
 2| 20150106|   14.18
 2| 20150107|   14.18
 2| 20150108|   14.18
 2| 20150109|   13.45
 3| 20150105|   15.69
 3| 20150106|   16.46
 3| 20150107|   16.41
 3| 20150108|   16.41
 3| 20150109|   16.41
```

However, the first row with NaN cannot be interpolated simply because there is no value ahead.
And in the actual case, there are many consecutive rows in the head of each symbol. I have just learnt python for a week, and that is really out of my reach.

---

Turns out I can use sth. called fillna()

> ```
> df=pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/stackoverflow.csv')
>   df1=df.replace(0,np.nan)
>   for i in range(1,len(df1)):
>       df2=df1[df1.symbol==i]
>       df3=pd.DataFrame(df2.interpolate())
>       df4=df3.fillna()
>       print(df4)
> ```

Thanks a lot for the inspiring comments. If you have a easier or more concise way, plz add your answer.(My method actually returns a mass, despite the result I want is mixed in it)

Comment: What do you mean by *nearest* value ? And for symbols other than 1 the value should be the mean of 14.91 and 13.45 all the time ? I don't really get it. Can you be more precise please ?

Comment: Sorry. I meant the nearest value within each symbol.

Comment: If there is only one value available, for example, the 0s in symbol 3, take the 16.41.

Comment: If there are two values available, take the mean of these two, such as the mean of 14.91 and 13.45 for 0s in symbol 2. It does not have to be the mean of 14.91 and 13.45 all the time for other symbols.

Comment: I think I understand, you're trying to simulate missing data for analysis, it's usually not a good idea. Anyway what you ask seems quite complicated and I don't think someone will just give you the answer without you showing what you tried. You didn't say which library you use but it's also possible there is already a tool for that, I know pandas has things like that.

Comment: So why don't you take the mean of your values in all the cases ?